# is it normal MVV takes three weeks?

Tags: visa, working-visas, netherlands

I am applying for an MVV visa to NL. My sponsor is recognized sponsor by IND. I have been told that because it is a recognized sponsor, it will take two weeks. Until now it is been three weeks and no answer.

Comment: Call IND and ask ETA for it

Comment: You have been told by who? The government of the Netherlands?

Comment: @EugenMartynov i did, they don't know

Answer (score 1):

I recently got approval on mvv, it took three weeks to get the approval letter so I think it's fine.
After that I have had to go to the Dutch embassy to get an mvv sticker on my passport, and that takes 1 or 2 weeks (it  goes to Washington, and I'm in south America)

Comment: do you mean that, in some instances, the visa is sent to the consulate in Washington DC, where the applicant picks it up? Wouldn't this depend on other factors?

Comment: @Dorothy I really don't know, I suppose that's just really the normal procedure.

Comment: @nMoncho was that in August? (The holiday month). For me, now it has been more than a month and yet no answer

Comment: @user2059935 yes totally. As far as I know the papers were turned in August 18th. Today I got the update on the sticker, my passport is ready for pick-up. Has the company gave any info?

Comment: @nMoncho Congratulations for your visa. I hope all goes good with you. The company said (two weeks ago) that we have to wait because it is holiday month in the Netherlands, and that makes sense, but now it has been 33 days. i applied on July 19. can I ask you please when did you submit your application to IND ?

Comment: @user2059935 since my employer was the one that submitted the application I can only guess the date, suppose the papers were turned in to the IND on July 18 o 19. That's why what you're telling me is striking me as odd, you should've your reply by now, sorry that can't give you any hints. Did you go to your local Dutch embassy?